# Easy way to upload Codeigniter files to a server

Tags: codeigniter, web, upload, file-manager

I have a server with all its need and I want to upload my site on it. I'm using Codeigniter and you know it has too much folders and files. so I need an easy way to upload all files to the file manager of my web server (in an easy way) .

Comment: use scp command of linux

Comment: 1.) Archive project; 2.) Upload to online server location; 3.) Unarchive it